# H2o Python - How do I determine the threshold for AUC

Tags: classification, python, accuracy, auc, h2o

I am new to H2o and I having trouble with AUC and Confusion Matrix

I have a classification model using H2o in Python for which the AUC = 71%

But the accuracy based on confusion Matrix is only 61%. I Understand that confusion matrix is based on Max F1

How do I determine for which threshold the accuracy will be 71%

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy and AUC are different things.

AUC stands for area under curve, and the *curve* is the one shown in your question: so the area on the bottom-right is 71% of the area of the whole rectangle.

Accuracy is `(true positive + true negative) / total`.

If you look at your model in H2O Flow (which is always listening on 127.0.0.1:54321 if you are running H2O locally), and find the ROC Curve section, you can see the threshold (and confusion matrix) for various metrics, including Max F1 and Accuracy.

You can get it within Python by calling `F1()` on either your model, or on a model performance object. See the Python tab at https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#f1